# paypal OAuthTokenCredential not found

Tags: php, paypal

I'm trying to integrate Paypal into a certain service, and using their guidelines there's a piece of code that looks like this

```
$cred = new OAuthTokenCredential($client,$secret, $sdkConfig);
```

And it throws an error

```
Class 'OAuthTokenCredential' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/algolive/test.php on line 12
```

I'm guessing the problem is somewhere in my require statements, which is why I'm asking this here.
I've, of course got one that looks like this

```
require "vendor/autoload.php";
```

In my `test.php`,
and the Paypal `autoload.php` has been configured

```
require_once 'composer/autoload_real.php';
return ComposerAutoloaderInit971745cb4894ea2202d406d3fd224121::getLoader();
```

I'm a bit new to this, so please bear with me, any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;

$cred = new OAuthTokenCredential('<clientId>', '<clientSecret>');
```

It is correct and tested.

Answer (score 0):

This is a namespace issue.
Try to insert this line before calling the method:

```
use PayPal\Auth;
$cred = new OAuthTokenCredential(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this question, As I found this all time up in search and not getting working --

So I tried below and its working fine.

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
use PayPal\Auth;
$cred = new PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(...);
```

hope it may help.